# Reading data into R causes Excel save error: "Someone else is working in '[file location]' right now."

Tags: r, excel, session, networking

EDIT: This is only happening on PC! No such issue with a Mac reading data into R.

I have to read files that are being updated on a day-to-day basis and stored on a shared drive.

If I have an R session open in which one of these files has been read, the file cannot be saved with new edits until I close my R session.

Is there a way to read a file into R while still allowing others to save new edits through Excel?

Edit: I am using package `xlsx` and function `read.xlsx`.

Comment: This may depend on which package and function you are using to read the Excel file.  Can you provide additional details?

Comment: package `xlsx` and function `read.xlsx`

Comment: I don't use the xlsx package. If you are just reading the Excel file and not writing back to it, you could try the "readxl" package.  It does the basics really well and does not depend on Java or other external dependencies.

Comment: Unfortunately readxl does not read passwords, which is why I have to use xlsx.